# Vue.js: como alterar um $state do Vuex que está em um v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, eu tenho alguns inputs atrelados a estados do Vuex:

```
<input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Filtre sua pesquisa" v-model="$store.state.controlAccessModule.filters.search" v-on:keyup.enter="loadEmployees()" />
```

Porém por padrões do Vuex, não devo alterar o $state diretamente pelo v-model, como devo fazer isso? Utilizar um $state no v-model é uma "anti pattern"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma `mutation` na sua `store`, uma `mutation` é utilizada para atualizar um valor no `state`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    username: ""
  },
  mutations: {
    setName(state, username) {
      state.username = username;
    }
  }
});

export default store;
```

Feito isso, você pode usar uma `computed` com `getter` e `setter` para atualizar o valor:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    username: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.username;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("setName", value);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Exemplo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-swirles-twkw0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark